# How to insert elements in an array of vectors?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

How to insert elements in it ?

```
vector <int> arr[10];
```

then how to insert more elements in the vector at position arr[i] when required?

Comment: vector <type> variable_name[size]; is the syntax of vector array.Add more information for better insight

Comment: i've used the correct syntax but it is not showing here i've used vector<int> arr[10];

Comment: `vector arr[10]` is an array of 10 vector's. Are you aware about this? Btw. if `vector` is `std::vector` it's a template. You have to use it with a template argument or it won't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   vector<int> v[3];  // here statically i have mentioned size,
                      // create 3 contiguous vectors of type int
                        //remember that it's is 2d kind
   v[0].push_back(2);

  v[0].push_back(3);


  v[1].push_back(3);


   // This is how you can add more elements than the
   // specified size-dynamically can change the size

   // This is the advantage of vector as we can 
   // dynamically add more elements

   cout<<v[0].front();  //2
   cout<<v[0].back();   //3
   cout<<v[1].at(0)  ;   //3

  //it's structure is something like this{{2,3},{3},{\0}}

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: For completeness, `at` may throw, `front()` and `end()` are UB if the container is empty.

Comment: I was asking about how to enter elements in an ARRAY of VECTORS not just  a vector.

Comment: @D_VsH_01 array of vectors has a syntax of vector<type>variable_name(size) ;i.e;the size is decided by us and normal vector is vector<type>variable_name so it has dynamic size .Not that the array of vector also has dynamic size.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35501439/array-of-vectors-or-vector-of-arrays    see this post for quick understanding

Comment: the same thing i am trying to ask how to enter elements in vector<int> arr[10]; not vector<int> arr(10);

Comment: @D_VsH_01 hope you get it .Accept it if you are satisfied

Comment: @D_VsH_01 I have modified the answer .Accept it if you get it and upvote it to encourage us