# STL list - What does [intNumber] do?

Tags: c++, list, stl

I have got a piece of code which defines a list from the STL. However, there is this "[256]" at the end that looks a bit like an array-declaration:

```
std::list<myStruct*> foo[256];
```

I already googled it and the whole thing does not seem to

- be a list of arrays ([That does not work in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826935/how-do-i-store-arrays-in-an-stl-list))
- limit the numbers of elements of the list ([There is a max_size function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/max_size/))

So what kind of container is this whole construct and what does this [256] do in this context?

Comment: Did you read the rest of the code you found, to look for examples how it gets accessed? Did you wirte some experimentatl code to try yourself?

Comment: @JaMiT It doesn't look like that outcome occurred to OP. They said it doesn't look like a _list of arrays_ and they are right.

Comment: @JaMiT Perhaps, but what is obvious to a veteran may not be obvious to a student. The question is perfectly reasonable, especially given the peculiar grammar for declaring arrays in C++. OP seems to have tried to discover the answer on their own and failed to do so. A chiding comment for simply not being able to see what is clear to us is neither necessary nor helpful.

Comment: @JaMiT I think my point is that the clause "if it looks like an array of lists" assumes that OP thinks it looks like an array of lists. They never gave any indication that they thought it did. It implies that the answer should be patently obvious to OP. If it were they would not have asked the question.

Comment: @JaMiT Yes, I agree that would have made the comment make a bit more sense. It seemed to start from a position that the OP already saw the full answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [array of vectors or vector of arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35501439/array-of-vectors-or-vector-of-arrays)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So what kind of container is this whole construct and what does this [256] do in this context?

```
std::list<myStruct*> foo[256];
```

`foo` is an array of 256 elements, each of which is a list of pointers to `myStruct`.

Think of it just like normal built-in type `int bar[256];` and just replacing `int` with `std::list<myStruct*>`